# How to detect Jboss version during installation?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

We are currently migrating from Jboss AS 4.2.3 to Jboss AS 7.1.1. When running the installation process we need to detect if the client already have Jboss installed and which version is it.

From what I can see ,in Jboss 4.2.3 there  is a readme.html file, while under Jboss 7 it is called readme.txt, is there a more unified/common way to detect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there is a standalone.xml file it should mean it is jboss as 7